# What resource do Markov and Shi mean when they estimate tensor contraction complexity?

Tags: computational-complexity, tensor-products, tensor

Markov and Shi in their paper [Simulating quantum computation by contracting tensor networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0511069) define the *contraction complexity* as follows (page 10):

*The complexity of π is the maximum degree of a merged vertex during the contraction process. The contraction complexity of G, denoted by cc(G), is the minimum complexity of a contraction ordering.*

**The question is: what real-life resource do authors mean by this definition?**

Consider the tensor contraction formula presented in the paper (page 8, formula 1). According to it, in order to calculate each of $2^{k+k^\prime}$ items of $f$ we are to perform $2^l$ multiplications which gives us $2^{k+k^\prime+l}$ per contraction i.e. the number of multiplications depends not only on the degree of contracted node and so it is probably not what authors mean.

[image]
[image]

Alternatively, the definition could be attributed to the number of writes to the memory holding the resulting tensor. It makes more sense but in my opinion is quite unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their section 4 they only contract one edge at a time, with the possibility of leaving self-loops. In your example, if your first contract one of the middle edges, it results in a single vertex with k edges to its left, $k'$ to its right, and $\ell-1$ self loops, which thus has degree $k+k'+\ell-1$. So I think the number of multiplication does depend only on the degree of the contracted vertex (as $2^{deg+1}$).

Comment: Thanks, I can see this place in paper now. Need to say, I'm discouraged by the author's logic, because their framework doesn't seem to handle the one-by-one contraction of parallel edges well, e.g. the definition of tree decomposition on page 5 seems to rely on the fact that there is no more than one edge between nodes.